# iOS - AddThis SDK with facebook looks terrible

Tags: ios, facebook, addthis

Using this code (the only relevant code I can find in their documentation)

```
[AddThisSDK shareURL:self.data.url
                  withService:@"facebook"
                        title:@"this is the title text"
                  description:@"the description"];
```

Results in a "Post to Wall" dialog with the following problems:

1. The "say something about this..." field is empty. Can we pre-populate that?
2. Below the "say something about this" field an "available on the android market" icon is displayed. This is iOS and I have no idea why this is showing up.
3. "Untitled Document" is displayed as the link header, with the title text and description beneath it. How can I replace "Untitled Document" with something more useful?

Comment: It looks like their SDK is version 0.2.0 so I wouldn't really expect it to be ready for production. You should look into implementing your own class to handle facebook post yourself and add AddThis methods within it if you'd like to use it for non FB posts.

Answer (score 2):

1. The "Say something about this..." cannot be overridden because it's a FB control and they don't want Apps to post content without the user's consent.  An alternative would be to use the FB API to post directly to the user's wall and not use the dialog.
2. The image being shown is pulled from the page you're trying to share.  Make sure you have the right Open Graph tags set.  You can use this page to see if your tags are correctly set:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

1. Not sure about the "Untitled Document" issue, if you haven't already, try the demo App and replace it with your variables and see if you get the same result.